Prove that the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {\sin(k)}{2^k}$ is Cauchy
How would one go about proving that the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {\sin(k)}{2^k}$ is a Cauchy sequence?
Here is my attempt before I got stuck:
$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n+p}\frac{\sin(k)}{2^k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k)}{2^k}\right|\\
=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{\sin(k)}{2^k}\right|\\
\leqslant\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}|\frac{\sin(k)}{2^k}|\\ <\frac{p}{2}
$$
It seems like the wrong move to write the final form in terms of $p$, as I'd expect it to be in terms of $n$ instead, but I haven't been able to find a way to get there.
Any hint or redirection would be appreciated!

From your second to last line we have:
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \left| \frac{\sin(k)}{2^k} \right| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{2^k}$$
$$ \le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{1-(1/2)} $$
$$ = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n $$
So we have:
$$ |a_n - a_{n+p}| \le 2^{-n} $$
Hence, it is Cauchy.

hey, you should use \cos(x) instead of cos(x) in $\LaTeX$.

You are already very very close. Note that $|\sin x| \leq 1$ so
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\left|\frac{\sin k}{2 ^k} \right| \leq\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{2 ^k} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \left( \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{p}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} \right)
$$
Can you conclude that the series is Cauchy from here?

you have :
$\sum \limits_{k=m}^{n} a^k = a^m \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-m} a^k = a^m \cdot \frac{1-a^{n-m+1}}{1-a}$
Using this identity, you'll get:
$\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}|\frac{\sin(k)}{2^k}| &\leq \sum \limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{2^k} \\ &\leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{1}{2^k} \\ &\leq_{p \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}
$
You now can conclude because you have a majoration in terms of n.

Just use the fact that $|\sin{x}|\leq 1$. Then you can use comparison test with the geometric series $\sum \frac{1}{2^k}$.This proves the convergence and then Cauchy. If you prefer a direct prove uses the fact that I mentioned above in your second last inequality to get part of the geometric series.
